# Greatest common divisor is a linear combination in countable case

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Show that the greatest common divisor of countably many numbers is their linear combination.

The proof for finitely many numbers is pretty simple - just prove it for $n=2$, and then you follow via induction:

let $A=\{pa+qb:p,q\in \mathbb Z, pa+qb\in \mathbb N^+\}$ and $m=\min A$.

Then: $\exists l,k\ \ a=lm+k$ and $k=0$ or $0<k<m$
so $a=lpa+lqb+k$, which gives: $k=(1-lp)a-qb$ so $k\in A \ \land \ k<m \ \ or \ \ k=0 $. The first one is always false, so $m|a$. The same reasoning gives that $m|b$, so $\forall r \ r|a \land \ r|b \ \Rightarrow \ r|m$. Also $m=pa+qb=pl_1r+ql_2r=r(pl_1+ql_2) \Rightarrow \ p|m$. Following by induction, the proof is finished.

But how can one change the reasoning to prove it in a countable case?

EDIT: Restated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider for $A$ the set of all finite linear-combinations of countably many integers $a_1,a_2,\dots$. Then $A$ also has a minimal positive element $m$, which is by definition a linear combination of finitely many of $a_i$s, and you can check, with the same argument that you gave, that each $a_i$ is divisible by $m$ (if not, the remainder of dividing $a_i$ by $m$ would be a smaller element of $A$.)

Then $m$ is a common divisor of each $a_i$. As $m$ is a (finite) linear combination of the $a_i$, it is divisible by their gcd, so $m$ itself must be that gcd.